# convert an xml file into File object in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get an xml file from user and extract data from it in android. how to convert the file into File object.

Here is my code when add the file button is clicked.

```
public void addFile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @NonNull Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            File file = createFile(path);       //next code snippet
     
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), createTableFromXml.class);
            Log.d("timeTable", "created table called");
            intent.putExtra("file", file.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

This is create file method

```
    private File createFile(Uri uri) {
        Log.d("timeTable", "selected path = " + uri.getPath());

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        String s = stringBuilder.toString();
        output.setText(s);         //this gives output of content of file


        File f = new File(s);        //it shows file empty
        
        return f;
    }
```

This calls an activity createTableFromXml which extracts data from that xml file.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_table_processing);

        File file = new File(getIntent().getExtras().getString("file"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document= null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(file);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            Log.d("timeTable", String.valueOf(e));         // error getting the file
        }

        NodeList subjectNameList = document.getElementsByTagName("Details");
        // some processing on this thats works fine in java using file path on my computer
}
```

File object is not created but the string has the data.

**How to take xml file from user and do processing on it.**

Comment: this is code where i tried to convert content from the file entered by user into a string and then when the string s is converted into File, on testing it shows File is empty but string gives the output.

Comment: `File f = new File(s); ` That makes no sense as s contains the text of a file. To use the File class s should contain a full file system path. So you did not create a file. I wonder why you want a File object as you know where the xml file resides and you already read its content.

Comment: `File file = createFile(path);  ` What is path? Didnt you mean `File file = createFile(uri);  `?

Comment: well YES, it's right in my code. i might have copied the old code here.

Comment: i also got the ans, uri can be directly passed in Intent

Answer (score 0):

Uri can be directly passed from one intent to another (no need of createFile method or do the conversion of Uri file)

to share data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), createxml.class);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

to get Uri and do operation on XML

```
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            document = builder.parse(is);

        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            Log.d("a", String.valueOf(e));
        }

        assert document != null;
        NodeList subjectNameList = document.getElementsByTagName("A"); 
        // some processing
```